# How to Pass arrays in clause to plsql procedure - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was playing around with the SQL developer and I ran into an issue here...  I want to pass in an array of IDs and select all the rows pointed by those IDs.

To pass an array and use it in a `SELECT` statement with an `IN` clause in Oracle, I have followed these steps:

1. Created a custom type in Oracle for the array datatype.

```sql
create or replace TYPE "NBR_ARRAY" as table of varchar2(30);
```

Used the below procedure to pass the array as a parameter.

```sql
DECLARE
    MID    varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
    I_ACCOUNT_NUM := ORADBA.CUST_ACCT_NBR_ARRAY(123); -- Initialize the PL/SQL table with values
            
     SELECT id into MID
     FROM ac WHERE  ID ='56' and nbr IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(NBR_ARRAY('123')));
        
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MID::'||MID);
END;
```

I see the result set as

```
Error report:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 10
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
```

Whereas I have a single record when I ran the below query itself.

```sql
select ID from  ORADBA.AC where ID ='56' and NBR='123'; -- able to see 56 in resultset
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the setup:

```sql
CREATE TYPE NBR_ARRAY as table of varchar2(30);

CREATE TABLE ac (id, nbr) AS
SELECT '56', '123' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  mid           VARCHAR2(1000);
  I_ACCOUNT_NUM NBR_ARRAY;
BEGIN
  I_ACCOUNT_NUM := NBR_ARRAY(123); -- Initialize the PL/SQL array with values
        
  SELECT id
  into   MID
  FROM   ac
  WHERE  ID ='56'
  AND    nbr IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(i_account_num));
    
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MID::'||MID);
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

```
MID::56
```

Or, more simply:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   ac
WHERE  ID ='56'
AND    nbr MEMBER OF NBR_ARRAY(123);
```

Which outputs:

| ID |
| --- |
| 56 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YQL00lBf)

Comment: It results in error 
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 7

Comment: is double quotes causing the no data found for create or replace TYPE "NBR_ARRAY"

Comment: @AjayTakur No, it is that you have no data in your `ac` table that matches. Your other query selects from `ORADBA.AC` and not `AC`, are you sure you are querying the correct table in the correct schema?

Answer (score 0):

I can use the string quoted values with comma-separated

```
DECLARE
  MID           VARCHAR2(1000);
  I_ACCOUNT_NUM NBR_ARRAY;
comma_separated_string     VARCHAR2(200):='';
BEGIN
  I_ACCOUNT_NUM := NBR_ARRAY(123); 
  MID_RESULT varchar2(20000);
        
    FOR i IN 1..I_ACCOUNT_NUM.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Element ' || i || ': ' || I_ACCOUNT_NUM(i));
        IF i = 1 THEN
            comma_separated_string := comma_separated_string || '''' || I_ACCOUNT_NUM(i) || '''';
        ELSE
            comma_separated_string := comma_separated_string || ',' || '''' || I_ACCOUNT_NUM(i) || '''';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('comma_separated_string ' ||comma_separated_string);
    
     MID:='SELECT id
  FROM   ac
  WHERE  ID =''56''
  AND    nbr IN ('||comma_separated_string||')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM ('||MID||')' INTO MID_RESULT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MID::'||MID);
END;
/
```